# Find users joined before certain time

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a newbie and really need guidance.

Basically I have a table with the following information:

```
UserID   UserName    D0J
983357   XXXXXXXX    25/08/2017
983358   XXXXXXXX    01/09/2017
983359   XXXXXXXX    03/09/2017
983360   XXXXXXXX    05/09/2017
.....
.....
```

What I want is to achieve is extract records of only those users who have joined the site 15 days before current date. I have tired googling around SO and many other sites but not able to figure out the proper way. I have tried using `lubridate` with no success.

Comment: what have you tried using `lubridate`? Please share that as well, it helps us debug.

Comment: thanks @ Aramis, whatever I tired was incorrect I am sure..something like first fetching the current time using Sys.Date() and then subtracting it with DoJ but it is giving NA or error. I have not saved the code and was rewriting on the same. :(

Answer (score 1):

tada :)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% filter(dmy(D0J) > as_date(Sys.Date()) - 15*days())
```

`dmy` (for day month year) formats your date correctly, and then it's a simple filter on an inequality, replace `>` with `>=` if relevant

**result**

```
  UserID UserName        D0J
1 983358 XXXXXXXX 01/09/2017
2 983359 XXXXXXXX 03/09/2017
3 983360 XXXXXXXX 05/09/2017
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="UserID   UserName    D0J
983357   XXXXXXXX    25/08/2017
                 983358   XXXXXXXX    01/09/2017
                 983359   XXXXXXXX    03/09/2017
                 983360   XXXXXXXX    05/09/2017",header=T,stringsAsFactor=F)
```

Comment: #Moody_Mudskipper, thank you very much mate. You rock...cheers. :)

Comment: Unable to install dplyr library....... Package dplyr is not available (for R version 3.1.0)...I Am stuck now... Even though I have the code available but can't do anything...any help please... Probably some other way to obtain the result.

Comment: That's odd, but luckily you don't need `dplyr`  just do `subset(df,dmy(D0J) > as_date(Sys.Date()) - 15*days())`

Comment: R is throwing error stating,  could not find function "dmy". 

Comment: you need to load `lubridate`, `library(lubridate)`, and possibly `install.packages("lubridate")`